# Why my RegexTokenizer transformation in PySpark gives me the opposite of the required pattern?

Tags: regex, pyspark, tokenize

When I use the **RegexTokenizer** from **pyspark.ml.feature** to tokenize sentences column in my dataframe to find all the word characters, I get the opposite of what I would get when the python **re** package is used for the same sentence. Here is the sample code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.feature import RegexTokenizer
spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .master("local") \
        .appName("Word list") \
        .getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame(data = [["Hi there, I have a question about RegexTokenizer, Could you 
                           please help me..."]], schema = ["Sentence"])

regexTokenizer = RegexTokenizer(inputCol="Sentence", outputCol="letters", pattern="\\w")
df = regexTokenizer.transform(df)
df.first()['letters']
```

This gives the following output:

```
[' ', ', ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ', ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '...']
```

On the other hand if I use the **re** module on the same sentence and use the same pattern to match the letters, using this code here:

```
import re
sentence = "Hi there, I have a question about RegexTokenizer, could you 
                           please help me..."
letters_list = re.findall("\\w", sentence)
print(letters_list)
```

I get the desired output as per the regular expression pattern as:

```
['H', 'i', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e', 'I', 'h', 'a', 'v', 'e', 'a', 
'q', 'u', 'e', 's', 't', 'i', 'o', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'o', 'u', 't', 
'R', 'e', 'g', 'e', 'x', 'T', 'o', 'k', 'e', 'n', 'i', 'z', 'e', 
'r', 'c', 'o', 'u', 'l', 'd', 'y', 'o', 'u', 'p', 'l', 'e', 'a', 
's', 'e', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'p', 'm', 'e']
```

I also found that I need to use \W instead of \w in pySpark to solve this problem. Why is this difference? Or have I misunderstood the usage of **pattern** argument in **RegexTokenizer**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what the [documentation on RegexTokenizer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.RegexTokenizer) says, on creation it has a parameter called `gaps`. In one mode, the regexp matches gaps (`true` and is the default), in other it matches tokens (not the gaps, `false`).

Try setting it manually to the value you need: in your case, `gaps = false`.